Why, intuitively speaking, are determinants related to pullbacks of alternating forms?
I recently encountered the following "coordinate-free" definition of the determinant. Let $k$ be a commutative ring and $M$ be a free module over $k$, with rank $n\in\mathbb N$. Let $\Lambda$ denote the module consisting of $n$-linear alternating forms $f:M^n\to k$, with pointwise addition and multiplication. If $u:M\to M$ is an endomorphism, we define the pullback $u^*:\Lambda\to\Lambda$ by $u^*f=f\circ(\underbrace{u,\dots, u}_{n})$. The pullback $u^*$ is an endomorphism of $\Lambda$, and since $\Lambda$ has rank $1$, it follows that $u^*$ is a scalar multiple of $\operatorname{id}_\Lambda$; this scalar is called the determinant of $u$.
Although I am able to parse this definition, it seems unclear to me what, intuitively speaking, this definition is "saying". Is there a way of showing that this definition is just a fancy way of restating the more familiar definitions of the determinant? I'm happy to see an answer that concentrates on the case $k=\mathbb R$ if it means we can appeal to some geometric intuition.

If you're willing to specialize to $\mathbb{R}$ for geometric intuition, you can view the elements of $\Lambda$ as measuring $n$-dimensional oriented volume, essentially uniquely (i.e. up to choice of unit volume). The pullback is how $u$ changes the measurement of oriented volume, and the determinant is just the factor by which $u$ scales oriented volume. This perspective is developed in other answers on this site.

@blargoner: Thanks, I'd be very happy if you could promote your comment to an answer. Would it be possible, however, if you could elaborate on how "the pullback is how $u$ changes the measurement of oriented volume" – that part wasn't so obvious to me.

Since we're working with a free module over a commutative ring, once we fix a basis then endomorphisms of $M$ are the same as $n{\times}n$ matrices over $k$. The usual determinant map $\det : k^{n{\times}n} \to k$ can be realized as a map $M^n \to k$ in the obvious way, and hence as an element of $\Lambda$. If $v$ is the matrix corresponding to $v_1,\dotsc,v_n \in M$ and $u'$ the matrix corresponding to $u$ then
$$
  (u^*\det)(v_1,\dotsc,v_n) = \det(uv_1,\dotsc,uv_n) = \det(u'v) = \det(u')\det(v) = \det(u')\det(v_1,\dotsc,v_n)
$$
thus $u^*\det = \det(u')\,\mathrm{id}_\Lambda$ and the definitions of determinant coincide.
